RabbitMQ get headers value (for example x-death)
I encountered a problem when working with the RabbitMQ bus.
I'm trying to get data from the BasicDeliverEventArgs.BasicProperties.Headers object (dictionary of headers) in the consumer event handler Received.
Headers itself is of type IDictionary<string, object>.
Headers object, which are "under the hood" an array of bytes, are normally given as:
Headers["header_name"] as byte[].
But if the header value is an array of byte arrays or a dictionary (as in the "x-death" header), then it gets the System.Collections.Generic.List`1 type and, naturally,
is not cast to either IList, or List, or a dict, or a byte[] array.
Accordingly, the question is: How to correctly get data from RabbitMQ headers containing arrays/dictionaries, also containing arrays in the
value element?
Header example: "x-death" - how to extract reason from its element?

There is no such type as System.Collections.Generic.List, it must be generic, such as System.Collections.Generic.List<string>

Type is not List, but List`1 (with tilda and 1)

That means it's a generic type, you're just looking at the ToString representation of the type here.

When sending as List<byte[]>, retrieving as List<object> works. You could try following sample.
Sender
var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
var header_dic = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "Name", "Alice" },
        { "Age", 25 },
    };
var header_ListBytes = new List<byte[]> 
    {
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("value1"),
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("value2")
    };
properties.Headers = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "x-death1", header_dic },
    { "x-death2", header_ListBytes }
};
channel.BasicPublish(exchange: string.Empty,routingKey: "hello", basicProperties: properties,body: body);

Receiver
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
{
    var headerObject1 = (Dictionary<string, object>)ea.BasicProperties.Headers["x-death1"];
    string name = Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])headerObject1["Name"]);
    int age = (int)headerObject1["Age"];
    Console.WriteLine($"{name} {age}");

    var headerObject2 = (List<object>)ea.BasicProperties.Headers["x-death2"];
    foreach (var byteObject in headerObject2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])byteObject));
    }
};

Test result

